# ARForms Plugin(Wordpress) does not display Multi-Selection element

Tags: wordpress, multi-select

I know that this is a very specific question but maybe someone here has an answer. I am using the ARForms plugin to create forms on my wordpress website. It works excellent and I was always very happy with it but since a few days the multi-select element stopped working.
In the editor where I created a form I can see the element but it does not appear on my website although the form itself including other elements works fine.

Maybe someone had the same problem and could help me.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Contact plugin developer since its premium plugin and prob will give you best solution.

Comment: Yes, you should check plugin documentation or contact the plugin support team.